# Rotating Seconds Hand in Pure CSS World Clock

Tags: html, css

I have the following Pure CSS Clock: http://cssdeck.com/labs/wall-clock-in-pure-css3

I've added the following code in the CSS styling that allows me to set where the hour and minutes hand is at:

```
body #clock .hh {
transform:rotate(352.5deg);
}

#clock .mm {
transform:rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
}

#clock .ss {
animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(1000,end);
-webkit-animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(1000,end);
}
```

And here is a fidde of it wth the above CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/vhft4g3z/

This works fine, however I am trying to apply the same degree method to the seconds .ss style like this:

```
#clock .ss {
transform:rotate(270deg);
animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(1000,end);
-webkit-animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(1000,end);
}
```

But unfortunately something seems to keep overriding the seconds hand. I know the .ss styling is working because if I add styling into the .ss class it applies it. However, it just doesnt seem to apply the rotation.

Any ideas how I can apply a rotation to make the seconds start at a given degree?

Comment: Did you looked on chrome inspector what rules are applying to your element?

Comment: I would have been extremely impressed if the clock would have shown the correct time, even just the minutes and seconds.